# how to display uploaded image in view using Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm having trouble in displaying my uploaded image. The image path at [webapp]/images/products/

First:
I want to display it inside CCGridView. I wrote:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'image-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
            'id',
            'title',
            'filename',
            //this is the image displaying part
            array(
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/products/" . $data->filename)',
            ),
            'product_id',
            //
            array(
                'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            ),
        ),
)); ?>
```

But the result only became like this:
[image: CCGridView]

Second:
I also want to display it in view.php

```
<?php if($model->filename) 
        $path = Yii::app()->baseUrl. '/../images/products/' . $model->id;
    echo CHtml::image($path,
            $model->title,
            array(
                'title' => $model->title,
                'style' => 'margin: 10px;',
    )); ?>
```

But the result is:
[image: view]

Please help me solving this. Many thanks!

Comment: Please check your path code is right

Comment: @Manisha Patel I've tried my path both '/images/products/' and '/../images/products/' but still both giving the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this maybe help:

```
CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/../images/products/" . $data->filename);
```

and check is exists file with name $data->filename

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The problem is in the controller. I added '.jpg' in my saveAs basePath, thats why the file cannot be "found". so this is the final answer CHtml::image(Yii::app()-baseUrl."/images/products".$data->filename.".jpg")

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
"value"=>'($data->picture !=="") ? CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseurl."/upload/technician/".$data->picture,"",array(\'width\'=>100, \'height\'=>50)) : ""',
```

I Hope it will help you...